# Update in PDO/SQL with a variable number of variables :)

Tags: php, sql, variables, pdo

I have a code that retrieves all the input data sent in a form. If the form had only 2 fields filled out, the PHP gets the value for only those 2 fields (the unchanged fields in the form are not submitted).

Then I would like to UPDATE a SQL table for those fields that I have retrieved with my PHP code. Here is where I am lost. I would need to specify in the SQL only the fields that I have received from the form, but this is variable. Maybe I received only 1 field, maybe I received 7 of the fields...

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))  {
echo $internalImage;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
 echo "Field Name: ".htmlspecialchars($key)." | Value: ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
    }
}
```

What would you suggest?

Comment: in a [tag wiki for PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) there is a complete solution for this very task. by the way, there shouldn't be any htmlspecialchars for any SQL part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct your query like this:

```
$values=array();

//this will be an array of possible fields that are in your table
$possible=array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');

$i=0;
$len=count($_POST);
$query='update table_name set ';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  $k=htmlspecialchars($key);
  $v=htmlspecialchars($value);
  if(in_array($k, $possible)){
    $query .= $k .' = ?'; //placeholder for a value
    $values[]=$v;  //append values to an array for later use
    if($i < ($len-1)) $query .= ', ';
    $i++;
  }
}
$query .= 'where table_id = ?';
$values[]=$table_id; //forgot that, append id of a row you are to update.
```

and then prepare and execute the query:

```
$db->prepare($query);
$db->execute($query, $values);
```

Comment: Actually the Column name is the name of an INPUT field in a form, so no one can manually change that. And those fields are named the same way as the columns in the table...

Comment: I believe any kid can use Firefox to change name of some field in your form and post it.

Comment: how could I add the `&` for multiple SETs except when there are no more results in the `foreach`

Comment: Ok, I will EDIT 2nd time and focus on one solution

Comment: Shouldn't the `' = ?'` have a comma at the end so other fields can be updated too? The issue would be the last comma should be suppressed.. :)

Comment: htmlspecialchars doesn't make anything safe

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Is that Vote Down to the answer because of the htmlspecialchars? Actually I think the answer is very good.