# PHP PDO with question mark placeholders with an IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Im trying to update a table using question mark placeholders, loosely based on this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146802/update-in-pdo-sql-with-a-variable-number-of-variables) now the problem is i only want to update if the variable has a value.
when using named place holders something like this works as expected:

```
$contactDetails= $db_con->prepare("UPDATE `userData` SET
             `name`= :name,
             `submitDate`= :submitDate,
             `contacts`= IF(:contacts = '', `contacts`, :contacts),
             `email`= :email
              WHERE `submit_id`= :submit_id");
```

Now in this case I'm using question mark placeholders, based on example referred above, and executing the statement as follows

```
$this_query= $db_con->prepare($query);
$this_query->execute($values);
```

so i changed `$values[]=$v;` to `$values[]= 'IF(""="",`'.$k.'`,'.$v .')';`
and it does not perform as excepted, the entire string is added to the database row including the 'IF….

when looking at the query log it shows
`UPDATE userData SET email = 'IF( \"\"=\"\",`email`, xxxx@xxx.com)',…` and so on
It seems to me that the IF is going as a string not as a conditional statement, is there a way around this?
Thanks

Comment: This `IF(""="",'.$k.','.$v .')';` is treated as text/data, not SQL. That's why you use prepares, right!?

Comment: I think `WHERE .. AND contacts = ''` would be more appropriate? (I'm not entirely sure how to read the question - as to which value is being checked, etc - but it should be solvable just using a WHERE clause or, if the value to be checked is the one *in* PHP, then simply don't execute the DML if not appropriate.)

Comment: @djot how could i get it as SQL not text/data?
Becouse everything else works fine other than that...

Comment: @user2246674 im not sure what u mean? the value being checked is from a php var, but it has to go in because it's in the $possible array, if u look at the link u will see what i mean.

Comment: So, you only want to update (set new data to) `contacts` when the given variable (which one is it? `$k`, `$v`) is not empty?

Comment: @djot yes when $v is not empty.
It's a short example there, but the table has more fields, and it's variable, that's why i used that loop.
If u take a look at example on link u will get a better idea of how that loop works

Comment: So you use that loop or not? Because in THIS questions there is no loop. Also, the "loop" only works without further conditions/checks as you see urself. You even can put the empty() check in the loop ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As opposed to creating the 2 arrays, i just create one string with all the variables in place and do the IF conditional check in SQL.
As i said before this is based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146802/update-in-pdo-sql-with-a-variable-number-of-variables) by Kitet.

```
<?php 

$values=array();

//this will be an array of possible fields that are in your table
$possible=array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');

$i=0;
$len=count($_POST);
$query='update table_name set ';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
$k=htmlspecialchars($key);
$v=htmlspecialchars($value);
if(in_array($k, $possible)){
$query .= '`' .$k .'`' .'= IF("'.$v .'"= "", `' .$k .'`, "' .$v .'")'; //changes here!!!

if($i < ($len-1)) $query .= ', ';
$i++;
}
}
$query .= 'where table_id = '.$table_id;

$update_data= $db_con->prepare($query); // I prepare the statement here as a safety net  
$update_data->execute(); // the execute it

?>
```

And now all works as expected :)
I hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $values = ARRAY();


  $sql_query = "UPDATE `userData` SET `name`= ?, `submitDate`= ?, ";
  $values[] = $variable_name; //:name, now ?
  $values[] = $variable_date; //:submitDate, now ?

  if (!empty($v)) {
    $sql_query .= "`contacts`= ?,";
    $values[] = $v; //:contacts, now ?
  }

  $sql_query .= "`email`= ? WHERE `submit_id`= ?;";
  $values[] = $variable_email; //:email, now ?
  $values[] = $variable_submit_id; //:submit_id, now ?

  $contactDetails= $db_con->prepare($sql_query);
  $this_query->execute($values);

?>
```

Comment: that will not work in this case, because the number if fields to update is variable, thats why i thought the best bet was to put check in SQL.
What i was trying to do was remove those quotes around the IF condition.
PS. the loop is in the link

Comment: You can't compare a stupid "do all - eyes wide shut" loop with special conditions like here. Only this single validation of `contacts` makes the "example" totally useless. It get's much more complicated as you even see here without the looping functionality.

Comment: it's just unfortunate as the query string  is almost as i need it to be except for the IF being treated as text not SQL